# Submenu doesn't display after adding window.onload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My submenu doesn't display after I add these lines line of code, what should I do instead?

Before I added this code, my submenu worked perfectly,  the problem I suspect is window.onload.

The below code work perfectly with the result I want, but it create another problem for me which is my submenu doesnt display anymore

```
  window.onload = function() 
  {
    var element = document.getElementById('<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>');
    var lblMsg = document.getElementById('<%=lblAttention.ClientID%>');

    lblMsg.style.display = 'none';


    if(element.innerHTML.length)
        lblMsg.style.display = 'inline';
    else
        lblMsg.style.display = 'none';

}
```

the error msg shown in browser

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_0248855d_ee1a_4a57_9508_a520e1f7f8b9$ctl00$MenuReport','Report')
```

Comment: Errors in console? Can you put your code in a jsfiddle.net? Are your IDs correct

Comment: yes, id correct, everything perform prefect, just the submennu problem

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your question. Please province more information or post a jsfiddle showing the problem if you can.

Comment: edited, i suspect there is window.onload problem~

Comment: Please post your code to JSFiddle to make it easier for the StackOverflow community to better understand and answer your question.

Comment: the problem i facing now is not the above code but i believe above code create another problem for me =(

Comment: We're not going to *guess* how you've implemented your menu. There is not enough information to answer your question with facts.

Comment: And what you posted is not an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion

Look at the page source

If you have something like

```
<body onload="somefunctiontoinitialisesubmenu()" ...>
```

MOVE the code to the onload like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>');
  var lblMsg = document.getElementById('<%=lblAttention.ClientID%>');
  var html = elem.innerHTML;
  lblMsg.style.display = html.length!=-1?'inline':'none';
  somefunctiontoinitialisesubmenu();
}
```